# How to add a goal/event/outcome in Sitecore from external system?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm using sitecore 8. Is it possible to add a goal/event/outcome from external system? for example from mobile/console/wcf custom aplication. I imagine I could be able to authorize in external system a contact with e-mail and then add an even in sitecore.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do it is using Sitecore FXM.

The Federated Experience Manager (FXM) is an application that allows you to track visitor interactions and generate analytics information on external, non-Sitecore websites with Sitecore. You can use FXM to implement personalization rules, create goals and events, and implement content profiling on an external website. You can also implement rules that include non-Sitecore sites in engagement plans, as well as track traffic from the external website in Experience Analytics.

To enable FXM functionality, a JavaScript tag is added to the external websites. This tags the external site and allows the FXM application to connect the external site's components to the Sitecore Experience Platform. FXM has a dedicated Experience Editor that allows you to assign marketing attributes, implement personalization rules and personalized content as you would on the Sitecore XP.

Comment: yes it will work but only if the external system is a website. What to do in situation when an external system is a console/desktop app?

Comment: will not work FXM for a desktop application. You can create some webservices, or to use sitecore client service to trigger goals when an event is trigger on your desktop application.